# Nitrous.io desktop fails to sync

Tags: nitrousio

Nitrous Desktop fails to sync with "Error: connection failed". Even after restart, delete and generate new SSH keys. I moved everything at ~/workspace but it stills says the same. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows then you will want to ensure that the **nitrous-ssh** app is not being blocked by your Windows firewall. You should have been prompted about this when first enabling File Sync, but if you did not check these boxes when first connecting then you will want to locate it within your firewall settings and allow it on all networks.

You may also want to check that the port which Nitrous Desktop uses is not being blocked by your network. The port can be found within the SSH URI field on the boxes page:

https://www.nitrous.io/app#/boxes

The port # is at the end of the SSH URI.